Mocking a gRPC server with wiremock-grpc-extension. Getting "Method not found error"
I have two services communicating with gRPC (one is gRPC server, and the other is gRPC client). I want to write a test for the gRPC client and want to mock the gRPC server.
I am trying to that by using wiremock-grpc-extension with a simple Java Maven project.

I have added the proto compiler maven plugin that generates sources for the proto file
I have configured the wiremock with the following code:

static void init() {
    WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(
            WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig()
                    .port(50051)
                    .withRootDirectory("src/test/resources/wiremock")
                    .extensions(new GrpcExtensionFactory())
    );

    server.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(server::stop));
    System.out.println("WireMock gRPC server is running at: " + server.baseUrl());

    Helloworld.HelloWorldRequest.Builder requestBodyBuilder = Helloworld.HelloWorldRequest.newBuilder().setName("john").setSurname("doe");

    Helloworld.HelloWorldResponse.Builder responseBodyBuilder = Helloworld.HelloWorldResponse.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello JD");

    WireMockGrpcService mockService =
            new WireMockGrpcService(
                    new WireMock(server.port()),
                    HelloWorldServiceGrpc.SERVICE_NAME
            );

    mockService.stubFor(
            method("SayHello")
                    .withRequestMessage(equalToMessage(requestBodyBuilder))
                    .willReturn(message(responseBodyBuilder))
    );
}

When I run the app and check the wiremock stubs from the web console, mocking configuration seems correct (see the below image)

However, when I run the app and call the SayHello method from Postman with a gRPC request, I get "Method Not Found" error.

While I cannot call the mock server with gRPC request, I can call with an HTTP POST strangely. I am trying to mock a gRPC server not an HTTP endpoint.

I think something is wrong with my mock server configuration code but couldn't figure out what. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

The WireMock gRPC extension works off of the descriptor files generated by the protoc compiler from your .proto files.  Are you generating the descriptor files ?  It wasn't obvious from your question.  I can see you are generating the code from the proto files but not sure about the descriptor files.

Thank you Lee, yes I generated the desc file but it was with .pb extension (I don't know why did I do that :) ). Now, I regenerated it after reading your comment with .desc extension and it worked. Thank you, you helped a lot !

Great news. Glad you got it working.
